# Hide Expand/Collapse button in Grid panel Group Header

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In my grid I would like to retain the grouping feature along with a `groupHeaderTpl` (Currently showing some custom text in the headers) , but I want to hide the [+/-] button from the header.

I tried it with CSS styles but without success. Can somebody help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Implement the **[collapsible](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping-cfg-collapsible)** property like this

```
features: [{ftype:'grouping', collapsible : false}]
```

Comment: It's not working. Only header text is removed but still [+/-] button exists. I don't want to remove the text, just want to hide the expand/collapse button.

Comment: @nari Than you implemented it in any other way. This only removes the group collapse ability, nothing else. I used this often so I am pretty sure. Also the API says nothing other... You should check your other properties. It may also be a bug in your extjs version. My last test was with 4.1.3