# contact list with grouped headers grid - in ext.js

Tags: javascript, extjs, custom-controls, gridpanel

Is there a simple way to add address book like group headers, to Ext.grid.Panel? (Ext.js 4.2.2).

Existing group headers contain a little expand box and are 'glued' to upper rows - unlike in contact list.

I mean, of course one can build his own, but in this case I just want to know if it's possible in a 'humane' way ;)

Otherwise, it would be great if someone could suggest a better approach / another js library for that can work well with ext.js.

Thanks

I am looking for the mere UI component, not the data model/controller part. Here's an illustration I painted..

[image]

Comment: Any address book / contact list js library suggestion will be most welcome.. I find it hard to look for something that I don't know if to call a widget/control/library/framework. I am new to js..

Comment: What address book do you mean? Or, can you provide a sketch, mockup images what the final result should be?

Comment: Painted an illustration ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354547/hide-expand-collapse-button-in-grid-panel-group-header) it seems that is possible to do that with Ext.js by disabling the collapse/expand button, and by controlling the padding of the group header, I can get it to look correctly as well.

Also, GWT (used by google) has also very useful control just for that case called a "Cell List" I would use if I would'nt have it the Ext.js way..